# Connecting from inside a swarm container to another manager host

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I've got a Docker swarm cluster where the manager nodes are in constant 'drain' mode, e.g. no container will ever run on them.
Now I'm running Jenkins in a container on a worker node and I'd like Jenkins to be able to deploy images to the swarm cluster.

My reasoning so far:

- Mounting /var/run/docker.sock is obviously not an option as the docker manager and Jenkins container are on different hosts and the local docker is not a swarm manager.
- Connecting from the Jenkins container to the local docker host using tcp has the same issues
- Adding the Jenkins container to the `--network host`, seems not to be possible: a container cannot also be in an overlay network at the same time

I assume this is quite a common use case, yet I haven't found a solution and maybe someone here has an idea. 
Thanks!

Comment: Just run the Docker client / library and point it at the manager node? (make sure it's secure over TLS of course)

Comment: yes, I agree. But how to get the IP connectivity from the container to the remote host?

Comment: Confused by your question.

Comment: Ok, I'm confused myself now as well. 
I guess I've discovered, that jenkins running inside the container can reach the manager-host and when using tls with certs/key this communication is also safe.